# Problems with my WHERE clause (SQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to write a query that returns the following columns:

```
owner_id,
number_of_concluded_bookings,
number_of_declined_bookings,
number_of_inquiries
```

However, the problem is that my WHERE clause messes up the query because I am querying the same table. Here is the code:

```
SELECT owner_id,
Count(*) AS number_of_cancelled_bookings
FROM bookings
WHERE state IN ('cancelled')
GROUP BY owner_id
ORDER BY 1;
```

It's easy to retrieve the columns individually, but I want all of them. Say I wanted `number_of_concluded_bookings` as well, that would mean I'd have to alter the WHERE clause ...

Help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you provide some sample data from the bookings table?

Comment: You need a conditional aggregate:  `COUNT(CASE WHEN state IN ('cancelled') THEN 1 END` or `SUM(CASE WHEN state IN ('cancelled') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`. Repeat this for each condition.

Comment: This good enough? https://gyazo.com/9d65a59eb26be135e6bf44b85ead15b7

Comment: @dnoeth would you mind adding that to my code completely explicitly? As the answer

Comment: See Parfait's answer below...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider conditional aggregations:

```
SELECT owner_id,
       SUM(CASE WHEN state='concluded' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS number_of_concluded_bookings,
       SUM(CASE WHEN state='cancelled' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS number_of_cancelled_bookings,
       SUM(CASE WHEN state='declined' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS number_of_declined_bookings,
       SUM(CASE WHEN state='inquiries' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS number_of_inquiries
FROM bookings
GROUP BY owner_id
```

Comment: Quick question! What do I do if I need to add multiple states to one column? Like this: `SUM(CASE WHEN state='inquiries', 'expired' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS number_of_inquiries`

Comment: Great to hear! You can use `IN()` and `OR` in `WHEN` clause and even nest `CASE` statements.